# How to rename a directory with the artifactId when using a Maven archetype?

Tags: maven, maven-3, archetypes

How can I rename a directory in a custom Maven archetype to be the contents of `${artifactId}`?

I have a directory named `service/App1` that I want to customize to be `service/${artifactId}`.

This directory is full of a bunch of files and other directories so I can't just create it with the `${artifactId}` I need to keep the contents intact and just rename it.

Comment: Are you using modules? Why can't you just rename the directory?

Comment: I want the directory to be parameterized based on the instance that is being created at the time of `mvn archetype:generate`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was looking into the same thing and found: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-191

Works like a charm!

Use _____artifactId_____ instead of ${artifactId}

Comment: yep, sorry, should have explicitly stated that

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the folder name **_*rootArtifactId*_**